# h2 database along with other datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, datasource, h2

I'm running h2 database with spring boot. Basic configuration

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Everything runs smoothly.

Now I want to define another Datasource bean in my application

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("oracleDatasource")
    public DataSource oracleDataSource(@Qualifier("oracleDBProperties") DataSourceProperties oracleDBProperties) {
        return oracleDBProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.oracle.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties oracleDBProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
```

```
spring.oracle.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:url:db
spring.oracle.datasource.username=test
spring.oracle.datasource.password=test
spring.oracle.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

The oracle datasource initializes successfully but this time h2 configuration is ignored. Looks like defining another DataSource bean  suppresses the spring's autoconfiguration for h2.

How can I avoid that suppression or is there a way to define h2 same way as I did for oracle?

I have tried to do the same type of bean config for h2 as I've done for oracle but it doesn't seem to work.

**UPDATE**

Fixed the problem with following

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.h2.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties h2DBProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("h2Datasource")
    public DataSource h2DataSource(@Qualifier("h2DBProperties") DataSourceProperties h2DBProperties) {
        return h2DBProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
```

```
spring.h2.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.h2.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.datasource.username=sa
spring.h2.datasource.password=
```

Adding the @Primary annotation didn't let anything suppress it. Although, still not sure to consider this as a right solution.

Comment: Please read the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Answer (score -1):

I have achieved the same thing some time before.

http://www.kode12.com/kode12/spring-boot/spring-boot-working-multiple-sql-database/